# Can I make a loop until `std::cin` see the `\n` character in the input buffer?

Tags: c++

Something like this..

```cpp
do{
    int x{};
    std::cin >> x;
}while(/*i want the condition mentioned here*/);
```

I mean, if the user input `x` and press *Enter*, I want the loop to end.
Can I do that?

Comment: Not if you read `int`s. All whitespace is equivalent when you read `int`s.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be a good way to do it, but how about `while (std::cin.peek() != '\n');`?

Comment: @Blaze It is quite the answer, but would you really recommend doing that? I mean, could that be a bad practice?

Comment: @Blaze I think that would break if there was white space at the end of a line

Comment: @AlanBirtles you're right, it would only fix OP's specific use case of looking for a `'\n'`. It wouldn't be very general purpose.

Comment: @MichaelD.Blake I would instead recommend molbdnilo's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common method is to read an entire line and then extract data from that line.

That is, a change of perspective from "read things until you encounter a newline character" to the slightly higher-level "read all the things on the line".

```
std::string line;
if (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::stringstream ls(line);
    int x = 0;
    while (ls >> x)
    {
        // Process x
    }
}
```

Comment: Blaze's answer is on the point. But this could also be a good alternate.